# Selector não aceita value=""

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que meu select fique vazio após o select anterior ser modificado. (Visto que os dois são interligados, onde o select1 é estado e conforme o estado é liberado as cidades no select2

Código HTML onde a pessoa seleciona o estado, após selecionado estado retorna as cidades do estado selecionado, e possui o botão buscar para buscar itens presentes na respectiva cidade.

```
<div class="row rol-inp">
                    <div class="row input-form">
                    <div id="slct-estado">
                            <span class="blt"></span>
                            <select id="selectEstado" name="estado" onchange="javascript: getCitiesFromState(this.value)">
                                <option value="">Estado </option>
                                <?php foreach ($estados as $est) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $est->UF; ?>"> <?php echo $est->UF; ?> </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row input-form">
                    <div id="slct-estado">
                            <span class="blt"></span>
                            <select id="cidadesSelect" name="cidades">
                                <option value=""> Cidade </option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row borda">
                    <a onclick="getStoresFromCity(this.value)" class="bt-concluir"><strong>Encontrar</strong></a>    
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

Abaixo, código que pega as cidades conforme estado, que já possue value="", mas não está funcionando.

```
 function getCitiesFromState(estado) {

    document.querySelector('select[name=cities]').value="";

    $.ajax({
        url: ROOT + LANG + "/facebook/getCitiesFromState",
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            estado: estado
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $("#cidadesSelect").html(html);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Como assim vazio? Você quer impedir que o usuário troque o estado depois que ele for selecionado?

Comment: Vc acha que seu problema tem a ver com PHP ou Java? Por que está usando essas tags?

Answer (score 2):

> Em vez de usar o seletor `select[name=cities]`, use o mesmo seletor do
>   `id` do select que está usando para preenchê-lo, que é
>   `#cidadesSelect`.

Você pode fazer de duas formas:

JavaScript puro:

```
document.querySelector('#cidadesSelect').innerHTML = '';
ou
document.getElementById('cidadesSelect').innerHTML = '';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#cidadesSelect').empty();
ou
$('#cidadesSelect').html('');
ou
$('#cidadesSelect option').remove();
```

Comment: Não deu certo nenhuma das soluções.

Comment: Mas o Ajax tá funcionando normal?

Comment: Em vez de usar `select[name=cities]`, use `#cidadesSelect`

Comment: Sim, funciona normal

Comment: #cidadesSelect também não funcionou irmão.

Comment: Então tem outro problema no seu código que não está na pergunta rs. Porque os métodos pra esvaziar um elemento são exatamente esses.

Comment: O código não possui problemas.Há algum problema que não estamos conseguindo enxergar.

Comment: Se está preenchendo o select, deveria esvaziar tb, já que tudo está na mesma função... não faz mt sentido isso não funcionar.

Comment: Cara, o `select` tem a propriedade `value` sim, tanto para leitura quanto para escrita. [óia isso](https://jsfiddle.net/wdnzrfom/1/)

Comment: E o código do Sam está correto, se tem algum erro é em outra parte do código que não está postada na pergunta. Você vinculou essa sua função a algum evento ou está chamando ela em algum momento?

Comment: @fernandosavio sim, vc pode atribuir `value` ao select, mas o uso do valor dele deveria vir do option selecionado.

Comment: Ah sim... Comentei mais pela frase que foi removida na edição. :D

Answer (score 0):

Testa assim:

```
$('#seuSelect').empty();
```

*Obs: Use o jQuery

Comment: Tentei e não funcionou também.

Comment: Oi Gabriel! Podes explicar porquê o _"Use o jQuery"_? Eu tenho opinião contrária, o jQuery neste caso é tiro de canhão para apanhar um pássaro.

Comment: Desculpe, eu ia escrever 'usei o jQuery' e faltou o 'i'. Faça como achar melhor, o importante é funcionar bem ;)